# Node asynchronous calls in sequence

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a couple of asynchronous requests that fetch some data from a url. The problem I am having is that I actually want to delay sending the json response until all requests have come back. The code looks something like this:

```
getFirstStuff(callback) //imagine this is async
{
    console.log('gettingFirstStuff');
    callback(stuff);
}

function getFurtherStuff(callback) //imagine this is async
{
    console.log('gettingFurtherStuff');
    callBack(thing);
}

function getStuff(callBack)
{

    getFirstStuff(function(stuff) // async
    {
        // stuff is an array of 3 items

        stuff = stuff.map(function(item) // map is synchronous
        {
            // For each item in stuff make another async request
            getFurtherStuff( function(thing) { // this is also async
                stuff.thing = thing;
            });

            return item;
        });

        callback(stuff); 
    });

}

router.get('/getstuff', function(req, res, next) {
    getStuff(function(stuff)
    {
       console.log('finished stuff');

       // RETURN RESPONSE AS JSON
       res.json(stuff);
    });
});
```

The output will be:

```
gettingFirstStuff
finished stuff
gettingFurtherStuff
gettingFurtherStuff
gettingFurtherStuff
```

but it should be:

```
gettingFirstStuff
gettingFurtherStuff
gettingFurtherStuff
gettingFurtherStuff
finished stuff
```

I understand that the reason is that getFurtherStuff is async and item will be returned from map before the getFurtherStuff async calls are back with a result. My question is, what is the standard way to wait for these calls to finish before calling the final callback 'callback(stuff)'

Comment: We use either a library called `async` or a control flow pattern like es6 generators with `co` or promises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways to solve this problem. Libraries like `async` and `queue` would probably be the best choice, if you have no problem adding dependencies.

The easiest option without external libs is just to count the async jobs and finish when they're all done:

```
// assuming stuff is an array
var counter = 0;
var jobCount = stuff.length;

// wrap callback in one that checks the counter
var doneCallback = function() {
    if (counter >= jobCount) {
        // we're ready to go
        callback(stuff);
    }
};

// run jobs
stuff.map(function(item) {
    getFurtherStuff(item, function(itemThing) {
        // process async response
        stuff.thing = itemThing;
        // increment counter;
        counter++;
        // call the wrapped callback, which won't fire
        // until all jobs are complete
        doneCallback();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install async
```

You would then simply throw your functions in to an async.parallel()

More info at https://www.npmjs.com/package/async